# Using a config file for JWT secret in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, jwt

I am learning Node.js, and while implementing JWT I want to put a separate config.js file to set the secret to generate and verify tokens, but I am having trouble with this.

First I create the config file as follows:

```
// JWT config
module.exports.jwt_secret = 'mysecret';
```

Then I require it at the API endpoint as:

```
const jwt_secret = require('../../../../../config');
```

And finally, I try to use it as follows:

```
jwt.verify(token, (jwt_secret), function(err, decoded) { ... }
```

But it does not work, so I tried a console.log with the jwt_secret, and I get this:

```
{ jwt_secret: 'mysecret' }
```

I checked code and searched here at Stack Overflow but I do not see how to solve this. I know probably it is pretty obvious but as I said I am quite new at programming and I am learning.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the expected behaviour or what's wrong? It seems like you `jwt_secret` is defined when config file is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a quick look at the `node-jsonwebtoken` api, `verify` seems to expect a string as the second argument. The way that you've set up your export and require means that your variable `jwt_secret` is the entire exports object from your config module, not the string. Try changing it to

`jwt.verify(token, jwt_secret.jwt_secret, function(err, decoded) { ... }`

and if that works, you may want to modify your require statement to something like

`const config = require('some/path/config');`

and then use `config.jwt_secret` as the argument. That's just style though, do what works for your project.

Comment: Thank you! It worked great, and I added the styling you commented.